# How to initialize a 2D array in a class?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, constructor

I have a Matrix class that looks something like this:

```
template<int R, int C>
class Matrix{
public:
    double matrix[R][C];
    Matrix(double n = 0)...{}
    ...
};

Matrix<2,3> m;
```

How do I initialize the array when creating a new matrix with the `n` in the c'tor, without iterating over the whole array cell by cell?

I've read here some answers about something called `memset`, but I can't use it at the moment (it's a part of homework assignment).

Comment: Initialise it to what, a "default" or a specific value?

Comment: I've mentioned that I want to initialize it with the `n` I get as input for the c'tor (default will be 0)

Comment: You can use a standard algorithm, but they would apply some form of iteration in the background anyway. Else you role your own iteration. `memset` can work in this case, but as you said, that's off the table.

Comment: Is it a quiz (not production code)? Only then: In a single threaded application you could use a static value set in Matrix' ctor to n. If you don't expose your implementation you can have a custom element type *containing* a double whose ctor initializes the contained double with n.

Comment: And by the way, memset iterates too! :-)

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to use std algorithms wherever possible:

```
    std::for_each(std::begin(matrix), std::end(matrix), 
              [n](double* row) { std::fill_n(row, C, n); } );
```

Full example:

```
template<int R, int C>
class Matrix{
public:
    double matrix[R][C];
    Matrix(double n = 0) {
         std::for_each(std::begin(matrix), std::end(matrix), 
                       [n](double* row) { std::fill_n(row, C, n); } );      
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the whole array cell be cell using clear, simple, obvious code. If your compiler is sensible (and why use it if it's not) it will understand precisely what you are doing and substitute in the optimal initialization mechanism for your platform.

Comment: is this the only way? i was hoping there's some shortcut to do this

Comment: What do you mean by "shortcut"? You mean less code?

Comment: I mean that I can do something like this `int a[2][3] = {0}` and I understand it will initialize the array to 0, I was hoping there's a way to do something like this when it's inside a class

Comment: but how can I do this as part of the c'tor?